# How to dismiss GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController from SKScene

Tags: swift, gamekit, skscene

How do you dismiss the `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` once a match is created? The available delegates seems to be only for when there is an error. There used to be one called `didFind`, but since its deprecated, I am struggling to figure out how to dismiss it once match is created or when player Taps on an existing match.

`receivedTurnEventFor` is the only follow up call and it has no reference to the match maker view controller.

I am loading `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController` on an `SKView` via

```
let viewController = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
        let vc = GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: r)
        vc.turnBasedMatchmakerDelegate = self
        viewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
            print("launched GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in player(_:receivedTurnEventFor:didBecomeActive:)

Comment: Would this dismiss the view controller if a turn happened to come in for a different match while the player was attempting to start a match?